# Ran out of disk space: will my live application mysql database be corrupted?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, drupal, disk, hard-drive

I have a large Drupal 7 site with many concurrent logged-in users running on a server where disk space recently ran out (MySQL InnoDB behind Memcached on Ubuntu 16.04). How/why this happened is a discussion for another day.

I've cleared up the disk space issue, and the site seems to be running fine as far as general interaction indicates, but Drupal log is full of errors like this:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3 Error writing file '/tmp/MYGWmIvU' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)' in /var/www/pixelscrapper.com/public_html/includes/database/database.inc:2229

**My question now is: will the mysql database that is running Drupal likely be corrupted/flaky at this point?** i.e. On a scale of 0-10, how vital is it that I restore the database to a point before the disk space ran out?

(Anything other than 0 means I will likely restore the database--but there are other things that went wrong as well here, which means that we would lose quite a few days of data if I need to restore, which is a huge drag. C'est la vie, etc.).

My assumption is that the data in MySQL may be more or less fine, but that I cannot rely on the integrity of the actual Drupal data (users, nodes, etc.) which are made up of collections of many database rows...

Comment: I think the space of your database current version maybe nearly full. Try to search the version of your database using if how many max of data can be stored.

Comment: A practical way to proceed would be to start your database and test your application against it. Did you try that ?

Comment: @GMB: I've edited the question to make it more clear. The site seems to be running fine as far as surface level interaction is concerned. My question really is about whether the database can be **guaranteed** to be okay, or not (my assumption is, not, but thought I would get other opinions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of space crashes can cause serious damages to databases. The sole fact that your database is able to startup and to run apparently as usual is already a good indication that it was not totally messed up by the incident.

Next thing you can do is to perform an in-depth scan using [the sqlcheck program](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) :

> The mysqlcheck client performs table maintenance: It checks, repairs, optimizes, or analyzes tables.

Analyze all tables in all databases :

```
$ mysqlcheck -A
```

Analyze and repair all tables in all databases :

```
$ mysqlcheck -A -r
```

NB : as explained in the documentation, you would better shutdown your application and make a backup before you run this.

Comment: Thanks GMB, this is very helpful. My assumption, though, is that even if my database is in okay shape, I can't trust my application data, since objects like users and nodes are made up of multiple db rows, and so some objects may only exist partially in the database (if mysql ran out of disk space after inserting, say, 10 of 20 rows). Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @JordanMagnuson I understand your doubts, they are relevant. It  may also depend on how you manage database transactions in your application : if you COMMIT only when a  consistent state is reached, the risk of having "partial objects" is less important.